# What format do WAV files need to have to be imported into the Korg D3200 Digital Recording Studio

Tags: audio-recording, recording

The title says it all...

What format do WAV files need to have to be imported into the Korg D3200 Digital Recording Studio?

I created 8 `WAV` files and burned them onto a CD so that I could import them into the [Korg D3200 Digital Recording Studio](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CEAQFjAA&url=http://www.korg.com/uploads/Support/D3200_E1_633661369446200000.pdf&ei=P_AYT-TgIY630AHIqMi0Cw&usg=AFQjCNGT6Hrm80S3CvT90XiykJ1z4FYOBg&sig2=iQHt0CYW7TJA5W2cjuzPzw) but when I get to the screen to select files for import, the device doesn't recognize that the CD has any compatible `WAV` files on it.

I've looked through the user manual (linked above) and couldn't find a definitive answer.

We exported 8 tracks off the device successfully and I'm guessing that the device probably wants files of the same format to be imported back into the console.

So really there are two questions here:

- What format should the `WAV` files be in order for the Korg D3200 to
  recognize & import the files?  How many channels should the `WAV` files be - Mono or Stereo?  What sampling rate should I use - 44100, for example.
- If the format of the exported `WAV` files are the correct format to
  use to import tracks back into the console, how can I view the
  properties of these exported `WAV` files so that I can get a better
  idea of how to save `WAV` files for import?

Another useful link for importing/exporting tracks into/from the Korg D3200 is this FAQ I found on the subject, but it doesn't specify any details of the compatible file format that should be used for importing.

Comment: I have never been able to import a WAV file into the Korg that was created on a Mac. It is just about the only reason I still have a Windows machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sampling frequency: 44.1 kHz, 48 kHz, *96 kHz
Bit depth: 16-bit, 24-bit
Number of channels: 1 (monaural), 2 (stereo)

From the D3200 [manual](http://www.korg.com/uploads/Support/D3200_E1_633661369446200000.pdf) (p.86) check out if the procedures you are doing are the correct ones :-/

Comment: thanks... ill give it a shot... i could have sworn that I already tried the 44.1 24 bit stereo, but it might not have been PCM

Comment: weird.... you know, it's technology con queso :-/